# Get data from Firebase and display in TableViewCell as post

Tags: swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I don't know how to get data from Firebase to my UITableView. All tutorials I have been watching used Firebase Authentication, in their videos all worked out fine but while trying to replicate it, I failed. 
Here is what I tried:

First there is my Database struct:

[image: Firebase Database structure]

And here is my code:

```
func observePosts(){
    let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
    postsRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        var tempPosts = [Post]()

        for child in snapshot.children {
            if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
            let dict = childSnapshot.value as? [String:Any],
            let text = dict["text":""] as? String
            {
                let post = Post(text: text)
                tempPosts.append(post)
            }
        }

        self.posts = tempPosts
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

So my question is: How do I get for example the message from a database structure like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let text = dict["text":""] as? String {
   let post = Post(text: text)
   tempPosts.append(post) }
```

This is wrong. There is nothing like `dict["text":""]` . First you dont have any data for text keyword , Second you dont write this `:""]` , you can call as dict["text"].

I think you solution is `let text = dict["title"] as? String` . But you architecture is wrong. You can declare just one keyword . title 1 , title 2 is wrong. You have to set just title.

Comment: My idea was actually to make the title and the message to key-value pair. Because they are always together. So the title will always be different. Cant I do it like this?

Comment: Not changing the name of the key! Like codeByThey said you shouldn't declare a key with multiple names!
You should have one single keyword for every child and maybe change the value as you want; the keyword can't be made like you did

Answer (score 1):

If you have followed YouTube tutorials, there's a high chance you did not modify your firebase rules to reflect on non-authenticated users. If you didn't, Firebase ignores every read/write request. To enable this, Edit your firebase rules by:

[image: img]

### Set the rules to TRUE

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

However, there's more to it. Don't do it this way unless you're in test mode. Google has some nice docs about it:

Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules.

Comment: I do now that. That was the answer to one of my earlier Problems :D

Comment: Can i keep it for future visitors? :3

Comment: In mind of my struggle... please! No-one should go through his code like a maniac and find the answer in the database rules :P